# apply function to all rows and columns in data frame except first column based on value in first column

Tags: r, dataframe, match, apply

Hello and hopefully I can explain this somewhat simply. I know this can be done with a loop, but that will take forever and I need this analysis to be done as part of a web page, so some sort of apply function should work much better hopefully.

I have 2 data frames. Data frame A has a list of distinct "anchors" and category values for each one (these are weighted mean values from an already-performed ddply).

```
anchor     ecomax    ecomin     volume     price    runtime
1   9482 0.12981362 0.5714286 0.12981362 0.1324330 1.00000000
2   9488 0.01458662 0.5544864 0.01458662 0.2967270 0.04166667
3   9549 0.09734398 0.5721429 0.09734398 0.1219376 1.00000000
4   9574 0.00902656 0.5505136 0.00902656 0.1455307 0.14652568
5   9575 0.00902656 0.5505136 0.00902656 0.1460919 0.14652568
6   9576 0.07608863 0.5613563 0.07608863 0.1114813 1.00000000
```

Data fram B is a larger data frame of the same category values (ignore the names for now), but there are multiple entries for each anchor.

```
  anchor ecomax_max_med ecomin_min_med volume_med price_med run_time_minimum_med
1   9482     0.12981362      0.5714286 0.12981362 0.1120882           1.00000000
2   9482     0.12981362      0.5714286 0.12981362 0.1686777           1.00000000
3   9488     0.01552049      0.5550000 0.01552049 0.2925363           0.04166667
4   9488     0.01292292      0.5535714 0.01292292 0.3041928           0.04166667
5   9549     0.09734398      0.5721429 0.09734398 0.1238916           1.00000000
6   9549     0.09734398      0.5721429 0.09734398 0.1184564           1.00000000
```

I want to subtract category values for B from their means (Data Frame A) based on its matching anchor; i.e. the first 2 rows of B (anchor 9482) will take differences from the first row of A (anchor 9482 mean), the next 2 rows of B (anchor 9488) will take differences from the next row of A (anchor 9488 mean), and so on.

The end result is to have each row/column (other than anchor) of new Data Frame C be the difference between the values in Data Frame B and their corresponding anchor means (Data Frame A). I hope this is fairly straight-forward; it can easily be done with a lengthy loop. I'm guessing that this requires some combination of "match" or "by", but I"m not sure and this has been extremely frustrating. Help!

Comment: Got to think with matrix-mind.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `data.table` solution.

It works by merging `A` and `B` by `anchor` (which is set as a key). It then evaluates the expression `e` which we have created to be

`list(ecomax_diff = ecomax_max_med - ecomax, ecomin_diff = ecomin_min_med - ecomin, volume_diff = volume_med - volume, price_diff = price_med - price, runtime_diff = run_time_minimum_med - runtime)`

using `mapply` , `sprintf` and `parse`.

The solution depends on passing corresponding column names for each data.table  to mapply.

```
library(data.table)
DA <- data.table(A)
DB <- data.table(B)
setkey(DA, 'anchor')
setkey(DB, 'anchor')

.calls <- mapply(sprintf, as.list(names(DA)[-1]), 
  as.list(names(DB)[-1]), as.list(names(DA)[-1]), 
  MoreArgs = list(fmt = '%s_diff = %s - %s'))

.e <- parse(text = sprintf('list(%s)', paste(.calls, collapse =', ')))


DA[DB, eval(.e)]
##  anchor ecomax_diff ecomin_diff volume_diff price_diff runtime_diff
## 1:   9482  0.00000000   0.0000000  0.00000000 -0.0203448            0
## 2:   9482  0.00000000   0.0000000  0.00000000  0.0362447            0
## 3:   9488  0.00093387   0.0005136  0.00093387 -0.0041907            0
## 4:   9488 -0.00166370  -0.0009150 -0.00166370  0.0074658            0
## 5:   9549  0.00000000   0.0000000  0.00000000  0.0019540            0
## 6:   9549  0.00000000   0.0000000  0.00000000 -0.0034812            0
```

- This is efficient because it uses *join inherited scope*. See the [data.table FAQ 1.11 -1.13](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf)

## A second, less efficient but perhaps easier to follow solution

```
 # calculate the difference between the respective columns (merged appropriately
 DIFF <- DB[, names(DB)[-1],with = F] - DA[DB][, names(DA)[-1], with = F]
 # combine with the anchor column from DB 
 DC <-  cbind(DB[,list(anchor)],DIFF)
 # rename with the names from A (otherwise they will have the same as DB
 setnames(DC, names(DA))
 # It creates the correct output !
 DC
 ##    anchor      ecomax      ecomin      volume      price      runtime
 ## 1:   9482  0.00000000   0.0000000  0.00000000 -0.0203448            0
 ## 2:   9482  0.00000000   0.0000000  0.00000000  0.0362447            0
 ## 3:   9488  0.00093387   0.0005136  0.00093387 -0.0041907            0
 ## 4:   9488 -0.00166370  -0.0009150 -0.00166370  0.0074658            0
 ## 5:   9549  0.00000000   0.0000000  0.00000000  0.0019540            0
 ## 6:   9549  0.00000000   0.0000000  0.00000000 -0.0034812            0
```

- Note: This may become even straightforward if `-.data.table` ignores character columns in future versions

Comment: +5 Although difficult to read (even for me!) it should be efficient. Did you realise that `DA[DB, eval(.e)]` isn't doing a full merge, but doing a _by-without-by_ using _join-inerited-scope_? That's pretty advanced so just wondered if it was by accident or not :)

Comment: Since `DA`'s key is unique, it might need `,mult="first"` to avoid the known slow down bug ([#2216](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2216&group_id=240&atid=975)).

Comment: Hm. There has to be simpler way, something like `B - A[B]`. On the face of it `-` works for `data.table`, but `B - A[B]` has a few potential feature requests needed (such as `-.data.table` could skip over `character` columns).

Comment: The join inherited scope is rather wasted on the small data set. I remember reading about it in one of the vignettes, and also a previous comment of yours that it is more efficient using eval() in j.

Comment: `DA[DB, eval(.e), mult = 'first']` appears to break the scoping. - It gives an error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'ecomax_max_med' not found`

Comment: Yup. Thats the crux that's vexed me a few times. Not sure how best to handle that, balanced with efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

```
datmer <- merge(datA, datB)
str(datmer)
#------------------    
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ anchor              : int  9482 9482 9488 9488 9549 9549
 $ ecomax              : num  0.1298 0.1298 0.0146 0.0146 0.0973 ...
 $ ecomin              : num  0.571 0.571 0.554 0.554 0.572 ...
 $ volume              : num  0.1298 0.1298 0.0146 0.0146 0.0973 ...
 $ price               : num  0.132 0.132 0.297 0.297 0.122 ...
 $ runtime             : num  1 1 0.0417 0.0417 1 ...
 $ ecomax_max_med      : num  0.1298 0.1298 0.0155 0.0129 0.0973 ...
 $ ecomin_min_med      : num  0.571 0.571 0.555 0.554 0.572 ...
 $ volume_med          : num  0.1298 0.1298 0.0155 0.0129 0.0973 ...
 $ price_med           : num  0.112 0.169 0.293 0.304 0.124 ...
 $ run_time_minimum_med: num  1 1 0.0417 0.0417 1 ...

 datmer2 <- cbind(datmer[,1, drop=FALSE], 
                  as.matrix(datmer[, 2:6])  - as.matrix(datmer[7:11]) )
 datmer2
#--------
  anchor      ecomax     ecomin      volume      price runtime
1   9482  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000  0.0203448       0
2   9482  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000 -0.0362447       0
3   9488 -0.00093387 -0.0005136 -0.00093387  0.0041907       0
4   9488  0.00166370  0.0009150  0.00166370 -0.0074658       0
5   9549  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000 -0.0019540       0
6   9549  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000  0.0034812       0
```

If you wanted to use the differences in the order that @mnel did it (B-A), you would also get the column names to be the same as those of the second dataframe:

```
 str( cbind(datmer[,1, drop=FALSE], as.matrix(datmer[7:11])  - as.matrix(datmer[2:6]) ) )
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ anchor              : int  9482 9482 9488 9488 9549 9549
 $ ecomax_max_med      : num  0 0 0.000934 -0.001664 0 ...
 $ ecomin_min_med      : num  0 0 0.000514 -0.000915 0 ...
 $ volume_med          : num  0 0 0.000934 -0.001664 0 ...
 $ price_med           : num  -0.02034 0.03624 -0.00419 0.00747 0.00195 ...
 $ run_time_minimum_med: num  0 0 0 0 0 0
```